# turtlebot - DB25 connector

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI all
Is it Possible to use the "TurtleCore™ expansion board" Instead of "TurtleBot Power and Sensor Board with 250°/sec gyro" ,Then Connect a x-tion to one of the usb ports? .Does the "TurtleCore™ expansion board" Included Gyro sensor like the "TurtleBot Power and Sensor Board"? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52215/turtlebot----db25-connector/) by [p4w](https://answers.ros.org/users/3896/p4w/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The two boards are not interchangeable, the TurtleCore board is meant to be runs as a standalone processor or as a means of communicating with the TurtleBot. While the gyro board is meant to provide gryo data and a means of powering the kinect sensor from the create. As far as I know the TurtleCore does not provide a gyro.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2013-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0